# Writing data( nodes pointers which point to data) to a file which can be reused later from visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, tree, nodes

I am working on a classification problem , for which I train a decision tree and for each node in the tree I store the clusters, centroids and a bunch of other stuff to identify the node in the tree.At the end of it I have a pointer which points to all this data. I wanted to know a way to write this to a file, so i can resuse it later. Also, what is the best format to write the data.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You will have to iterate over the tree, and XML is probably a good format (it itself is a tree structure).

Comment: @clcto , I am a bit confused on the iteration part, do I just start with the rootaddress and iterate it to get the data, or do i have to separately do it for different data structures in the each node .